# Using the SQLite LIKE clause

Tags: sqlite

Kindly review this simple [SQLite-fiddle](http://www.sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-55cb67d0c2c55d1da264f32b37413cf4a4e7d37d8ace891124) .

If any word in the column `ITEM` of table `TWO` matches any word in the column `NAME_2` of table `ONE`, there should be a result(s).

Tried many permutes, yet not sure how to form the query for achieving this. Should the `GLOB`clause be used instead of `LIKE`, or perhaps some other wildcard patterns?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not do an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Can you please post the query? The fiddle is failing :s

Comment: @xcoder, didn't know that its a possibility. Some more light please? Thought this was plain simple pattern matching... so no clue how to make an INNER JOIN to solve this.

Comment: @KAD, yes the fiddle fails. That's the problem. Putting the string literally and exactly, works though. Cannot figure out why.

Comment: Hi, not sure if this can be done in your case. But if you are looking for exact match. Then you can do something like Select * from Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ITEM = T2.NAME_2. Obviously, if you need an instring search, thats another thing, can you specify?

Comment: @xcoder, the INNER JOIN would be an exact match. I am looking for an instring match, but stuck with SQLite version 3.7.11. How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I think you can make use of `instr` as well. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 where instr(T2.NAME_2,T1.ITEM);
```

The above should return rows where T2.NAME contains a string = T1.ITEM

Comment: Yes, aware of this, but unfortunately stuck with version 3.7.11... It is surely the right answer for version 3.7.15 and above.